# bayespy - does it work online?

Tags: python, runtime, bayesian-networks

how to define the chain if it is intended to work online i.e. the length of the chain will change at each iteration in a cumulative manner?

for example the bayespy categorical markov chain function asks for the number of states in the chain if it cannot infer it (which by providing it, it means the length is fixed) and also the evidence variables observed with `observe()` from `bayespy.inference.vmp.nodes.expfamily.ExponentialFamily module`, it needs to have the same length as the chain. The data associated with such variables instead is known only at runtime for me.

Comment: did you have any idea about `RealTime` ? (it's got **`<60ms`** delay on single transmit/receive, a dream ? yes !) But you got high speed communication if used `mac-based` protocols !(of course on `LAN` not on `NET`)

Comment: hey, thanks but i ve edited the question as i meant to ask how bayespy can work online